# What happens when nobody can build in Catan Junior?

Tags: catan-junior

The game says it’s over when someone builds all 7 pirate lairs. However in our 4 player game we ran out of available spaces before anyone had run out of lairs. The rules don’t seem to describe this scenario. What is supposed to happen?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding in how you are playing and it appears you are placing the ships in the wrong places. It appears you are placing then in the spots for pirates coves instead of in between like they should be.

https://www.ultraboardgames.com/catan/junior.php

[image: Picture showing ship placement]

There is also a board game geek thread about it with this as well

[https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1224505/catan-junior-three-player-deadlock\](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1224505/catan-junior-three-player-deadlock%5C)

> A little late, obviously, but are you putting the ships in the circles instead of on the dotted lines?

Comment: Thanks! Yep we completely missed that ships go on lines instead of circles.